# How do you use alternate costumes?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

Looking at the [wiki page for any character](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/The_Hunter), they show the sprites for the character in an alternate costume. How are these used or unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an alternate costume, you first have to beat the game with that character by killing your past.

Once you've done that, the alternate costume will be lying said character when you choose them at the start of the game.  You can just go and use it to switch to it.

Comment: You have to beat the game AND kill your past with that character.

Comment: To be clear, by beating the game - do you mean defeating the High Dragun?

Comment: @QuestionMarks No, I mean by killing your past just like PapaStan said.